# Populate field with current time

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, attribute-table, time

I am trying to populate a field with the current time. Here is what I tried that did not work:

```
Start editing
Open Attribute Table
Add Field -> Name: time
    Type: Date
Right Click on Field Name (time)
    Open FieldCalculator
        Parser: Python
        Type: Date
```

Then I basically tried all of these expressions:

```
time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

That gives me the date, not the time

```
datetime.datetime.now( )
```

That gave me DATE and TIME. But as soon as I saved the changes, the time disappears.

(If the time would stay there I could do something with the FieldCalculator to populate another column like `!time![:x]`)

```
datetime.timedelta(seconds=0)
```

That gave me `<Null>`.

Am I missing a step or something?

Comment: Try `time.strftime('%H:%M')` to get hours and minutes? (Python [documentation on strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior))

Comment: That worked sort of. In the edit session it gave me the current time, but as soon as I quit the edit session and save the changes, it sets everything to 12AM

Comment: @Erica sorry, didnt link you in my comment

Answer (score 2):

The date field stores the full date. It is your system (combined with the type of database) that defines how a date will be displayed.

if you want to store a string with the time using your own format, you can use a text field, then something like

```
str(datetime.datetime.now( )).split()[1]
```

will work, or, better, directly use the date formatting from [strftime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/). In your case, H for hours and M for minutes, optionnally S for seconds

```
time.strftime('%H:%M')
```

or

```
time.strftime('%H:%M.%S')
```

Note that an

Comment: thanks. the `str(datetime.datetime.now( )).split()[1]` works fine. But the `time.strftime('%H:%M')` does not work. See my comment on my question.

Comment: what kind of database did you use ? I could not reproduce your problem in a gdb.

Comment: I tried to perform the operation on a table in a shapefile. ArcGis for Desktop 10.2.2